# how to convert MS office 2013 power point presentation to html using C#

Tags: .net, html, c#-4.0, powerpoint

I have already idea about converting the MS office .ppt file to html using c# with MS office interop library references but i want particularly to convert .pptx file to html. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this VBA Snippet

```
Sub SaveAsMHT()
  With ActivePresentation
    Call .SaveAs("c:\temp\SingleFile.mht",ppSaveAsWebArchive,false)
  End With
End Sub
```

Credit: [PPTFaq](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01077_How_can_I_convert_PowerPoint_2010_to_HTML_-where-s_the_Save_As_Web_Page_command--.htm)

Comment: No, i don't want to do programming on macros, and perhaps the code above is for macro programming, and also this code is for conversion of 2010 or lower version of power point. I want logic to convert presentation made in MS office 2013 power point tool and will use that code in my web application.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize you wanted this for a web application. That significantly changes your request.

Comment: In any case, the VBA @EliSadoff quoted would only work with PPT 2010 and prior. MS completely removed the ability to save as HTML/MHTML, even via the object model, from 2013 and later versions.  I've updated the PPT FAQ to make this more emphatic.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg thank you so much for writing PPT FAQ. Sorry for quoting something that wouldn't work. Your a VBA expert, which is a dirty job but someone needs to do it.

Comment: No worries, @EliSadoff. I wrote that fairly soon after PPT 2010 came out; I didn't think to update it after SaveAs HTML went away in 2013.  So really, you did me a favor by reminding me that the page needed to be updated.  Thanks!